# QML window prevent focus stealing

Tags: qt, qml, qt5

I'm developing hybrid qml/qwidget application with qml-based popup notification system. Notifications are stored in list model and I'm using QML `Instantiator` to create and handle popups.

My problem is that every time new notification pops up it steals focus from the main widow. Note, that I'm using QMainWindow as a main window for the application.

Here is QML code snippet:

```
Instantiator {
id: instantiator
model: notificationCenter
delegate:
    Window {
    id: notificationWindow
    color: "transparent"
...
```

Variable `notificationCenter` is `QAbstractListModel`-derived object that contains all active notifications and some settings, including list of notifications:

```
QList <iNotification *> m_notifications;
```

It also contains `QQmlEngine` and `QQmlComponent` to load QML code with notification interface.

Popup is implemented using animation of QML window Y coordinate. Notification object is created with default `y = QApplication::desktop()->availableGeometry().height() - 10` after adding new notification to the list `recalculateGeometry` function is called, which recalculates Y coordinates of all notifications and animates all notification windows:

```
Behavior on y {
    NumberAnimation {
        duration: 300
    }
}
```

So the popup itself is handled by `Instantiator`

Adding `Qt.WA_ShowWithoutActivating` to window flags has no effect.

UPD:
I've managed to fix this. Window steals focus with the following flags:

```
flags: Qt.FramelessWindowHint | Qt.WA_ShowWithoutActivating |  Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint
```

But (surprisingly) does not steal focus with  the following flags:

```
flags: Qt.FramelessWindowHint | Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint | Qt.Popup
```

Comment: And the popup code?

Comment: @Mitch edited question to clarify the popup system

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution found, use

```
flags: Qt.FramelessWindowHint | Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint | Qt.Popup
```

instead of

```
flags: Qt.FramelessWindowHint | Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint | Qt.WA_ShowWithoutActivating
```